# Посоветуйте удобный клиент Mysql для удаленного соединения

Tags: sql, mysql

Основное требование - простота работы со строками и множественное добавление строк и выборка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL-Front. Работаю с ней около 2 месяцев, нареканий никаких нет.

Answer (score 2):

heidisql

http://www.heidisql.com/

Answer (score 1):

<sarcasm> SSH </sarcasm>

А вообще, вы же, наверное, в phpStorm работаете, там есть менеджеры БД.